configure scala/java in vscode like in maven
I have an ubuntu EC2 machine which I SSH into using VS Code. I have a scala spark project. I have set all env variables and when I run mvn clean install -U and mvn test it compiles the project and runs all unit tests succesfully. But in VS code, if I click on a test it fails with some non-helpful error message:
Note it only fails in the spark steps. I am new to scala/java, so it is probably some silly VS Code setting I am missing.
In settings.json I tried to add:
    "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",

but it gets "greyed out" and says "This setting cannot be applied int his window. It will be applied when you open a local window.". Below some more information on the setup.
> scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.12 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL

> java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_432"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_432-8u432-ga~us1-0ubuntu2~22.04-ga)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.432-bga, mixed mode)

> mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_432, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.8.0-1019-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

> mvn clean install -U
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:51 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-10T16:13:11+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

> mvn test

2024-12-10 16:18:08 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 93 finished: collect at TestUtils.scala:13, took 0.036191 s
- Case 2: two columns to trim
Run completed in 2 minutes, 51 seconds.
Total number of tests run: 15
Suites: completed 3, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 15, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
All tests passed.
2024-12-10 16:18:08 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook



Not sure if it is the same issue you have because you didn't give details about how you setup vs code or what you tried. Someone reported a similar issue (I guess) at github vscode maven - This setting cannot be applied int his window
